# ResourceNotFoundException while trying to parse xml file in android

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm trying to parse an xml file and extract data from it to display in my android app. 
The xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record>
<study id="1">
    <topic>SAX Parser</topic>
    <content>Learn how to parse XML using SAXParser</content>
    <author>Pete Houston</author>
    <date>02-Oct-2011</date>
</study>
```

The file is stored in res/raw folder. The android activity calls a function which tries to read the xml file and parses it to retrieve data,which is then stored into an object of type Study (defined by me). This object is then returned by the function.

The skeleton structure of my code is given below:

```
public class XmlParserActivity extends Activity {
Study study=null;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//...android code and some variable initializations
    try{
    study = parseXml(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.record));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
}
public Study parseXml(InputStream is){
    //code for parsing the input stream
    return study;
}
```

When I launch the app in an emulator it crashes and produces android.content.res.ResourcesNotFoundException. Is there something wrong with the way I am accessing the xml file? Or do I need to set some permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file? I have searched this site and other sites but have not found a satisfactory solution to my problem. Any guidance will be deeply appreciated.

logcat messages:

```
01-09 15:49:55.801: I/Process(1152): Sending signal. PID: 1152 SIG: 9
01-09 15:50:04.174: E/Trace(1198): error opening trace file: No such file or directory(2)
01-09 15:50:04.992: W/ResourceType(1198): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
01-09 15:50:05.002: D/AndroidRuntime(1198): Shutting down VM
01-09 15:50:05.002: W/dalvikvm(1198): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.androidxmlparser/com.example.androidxmlparser.XmlParserActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at com.example.androidxmlparser.XmlParserActivity.onCreate(XmlParserActivity.java:34)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-09 15:50:05.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1198):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: what's the name of the xml file ?

Comment: name of the file is record.xml

Comment: I'm getting the exception on the line:
    study = parseXml(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.record));

Comment: I am using Android 4.2 to compile and Android 4.0 as the target sdk

Comment: Can you post the logcat in a code block instead so that it's a bit more readable?

Comment: I edited it.please check

Comment: From the logcat error, your problem might not be with the code that you posted, it's at line 34 when you're setting the text of a textview

Comment: Thanks Matt, I have now resolved the error. I was trying to display an int variable in a TextView without converting it to String first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access a string resource that cannot be found.

As Matt Taylor suggests, you should check line 34 of your activity, and find which string resource is wrong.

Comment: I commented out the line and now the code works! I think it was because in the statement 
        tvId.setText(study.mId);

the variable study.mId is of type int

Answer (score 0):

Further to fiddler's comment on your question, I've just seen what I think is the problem:

Your xml file just needs to contain:

```
<study id="1">
    <topic>SAX Parser</topic>
    <content>Learn how to parse XML using SAXParser</content>
    <author>Pete Houston</author>
    <date>02-Oct-2011</date>
</study>
```

And you access it using:
`getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.<xml file name (without.xml)>);`

For example, if it was called `xmldata.xml` you'd use `R.raw.xmldata`

Comment: I tried it out.Still does not work.Shall I post the logcat error messages?

Comment: Yeah, good idea - and for future reference, if you're asking for help on an error, always post logcat, as it helps us see exactly what the problem is